# Why is there a difference in output between printf and cout?

Tags: c++

The code using printf and cout:

```
int a=0;

a=printf("Hello World");

cout<<" "<<a;
```

Output :
11Hello World

The code using printf:

```
int a=0;

a=printf("Hello World");

printf("%d ",a);
```

Output :
Hello World11

Comment: There isn't a question here. Also, why is the question tagged C if it's a C++ question?

Comment: They're two different output systems: you shouldn't mix them.  There is also puts, cerr and fprintf(stderr.  Some are buffered, some are not.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://ideone.com/vsHdJG

Comment: Under normal circumstances `std::cout` is synchronized with `stdout` (used by printf). Though they are technically different streams the library tries to keep them in sync. This of course is busy work and  "some" applications turn off this synchronization (which seems to have been done somewhere in your code not shown) and simply only use one technique. If you turn off the synchronization then they are completely independent streams that at some point dump data to the terminal (or whatever output device the application is connected to).

Comment: ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
Sorry This line was included which caused difference in output

Answer (score 4):

You must have disabled synchronization between `std::cout` and C API?
If it is enabled I [can't reproduced it](https://www.godbolt.org/z/KqWq6s)

If I disable this synchronization I [reproduce observed output](https://www.godbolt.org/z/5dMKnE).

For more information read about [std::ios::sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: If you're going to make a comment into an answer, at least remove the follow up question.

Comment: Change the question into a statement: "You must have disabled synchronization"

Comment: ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
cin.tie(NULL);
was used in the code for fast I/O